# monte carlo simulation: multiple variables

Tags: statistics

I am reading about the merton model in finance. It depends on multiple distributions. I want to use monte carlo simulation but I've a little question about this.

If we have a statistical model that uses multiple random numbers. Let's say that we take $n$ random numbers out of $U([0,1])$ and we take $m$ random numbers out of the standard normal distribution in our model that we uses. I've seen the monte carlo simulation when we take only one random number, if we want to extend it to the case that we have multiple random numbers. How do we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has $N$ uncorrelated random variables, then one can simply generate $N$ series of uncorrelated random draws.

Now suppose one has $N$ random variables, which have non-zero correlation among them - the correlation is specified by a correlation matrix.  To generate the correlated random draws, first generate $N$ series of uncorrelated random draws.  Next, using a methodology such as L-U decomposition, if applicable, or Singular-Value Decomposition, one can use the $N$ series of uncorrelated draws to generate $N$ series of correlated random draws.

Comment: Is it true that you need to have more simulations to have a 'stable' answer ?

Comment: What do you mean by "more simulations" and "stable?"  Suppose that for 1 random variable, N_S simulations suffice.  Then, it is interesting that for $N$ random variables, one needs only $N \times N_S$ random draws, not $(N_S)^N$ draws.